# Function arguments for side effects

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Can I use arguments to keep functions pure?

Example:

```
const activateAUser = (user, log) => {
  const newUser = {...user, active: true};

  log("User activated");

  return newUser;
}

activateAUser({active: false, name: 'John'}, console.log);
```

Can we say in this case, that function `activateAnUser` is pure?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, yes you can. That's the only way I can think of of passing new values without side effects, i.e. variables

Comment: In any case it's ungrammatical (should be `activateAUser`). :-)

Comment: Of course you can do it

Comment: @MatheusAvellar But if it is true, that good OOP is a FP, if we use IoC container and inject dependencies into constructor, then a class is just functions container isnt it?

Comment: I haven't messed much with JS classes yet, but quickly scanning over the [MDN page on classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), it does look like it is

Comment: ok I can answer myself now. No It's not - constructor's parameters are out-of-context for caller. So if we call `logger.log()` results side effects unexceptionally.

Comment: but in the other hand if do `injectLogger = (log) => (user) => activateAUser(user, log)` and then `wrappedLogger = injectLogger(console.log)` then `wrappedLogger({...})` has unexpected side effects as well...

Comment: Since `log`'s return value isn't used anywhere, it *must* have a side effect if it's not a complete noop, so `activateUser` "knowingly" is calling a side-effect function, regardless of whether it acquires it itself or through DI, and so arguably is itself impure.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of arguing about what the exact definition of 'purity' is, I'm going to offer another viewpoint: namely that your example is sub-optimal. Why are you conflating user activation with logging? You've attempted to compose two unrelated things, but you've done the composition *backwards*.

```
var log = f => (...args) => {
  var result = f(...args);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
};

var activateUser = log(user => ({...user, active: true}));
```

Now `activateUser` (or at least the argument function) is definitely pure, `log` is definitely not, and we've side-stepped a bootless argument. Any time you find yourself debating (internally or externally) these kinds of things its time to rethink your design.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself a simple question: Can I replace the function call with its return value without altering the behavior of the program? If you answer this question with yes, it is a pure, otherwise an impure function.

`console.log` is inherently impure, because it alters the behavior without providing a meaningful return value - it merely returns `undefined`. Hence, `activateAUser` is impure too.

Just use `tap` to separate logging:

```js
const tap = f => x => (f(x), x);

const log = prefix => x => console.log(prefix, x);

const activateAUser = user => {
  const newUser = Object.assign({}, user, {active: true});
  return newUser;
}

tap(log("user activated")) (activateAUser({active: false, name: 'John'}));
```

Comment: `tap` <3 <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 1):

**Free variables and constants are not considered impure**

> Can I use arguments to keep functions pure?

Are you suggesting that you need a `log` parameter to keep your function pure? The following is a completely pure program

```js
const point2degrees = (x,y) =>
  Math.atan2(y,x) * 180 / Math.PI
  
console.log(point2degrees(3,3)) // 45•
console.log(point2degrees(1,2)) // 63•
```

Just because our function references free variables and constants `Math.atan2`, `*`, `180`, `/`, or `Math.PI` doesn't make it any less pure. In other words, **don't** go writing this

```
// no, bad
const point2degrees = (x,y,atan,pi) =>
  atan(y,2) * 180 / pi

// this is ludicrous
console.log(point2degrees(3, 3, Math.atan2, Math.PI))
```

---

**Side effects are impure**

However, if we write something out to the console, that *is* impure – logging is a side effect and it should be contained when possible.

Imagine a simple function, `add`, in my handy library. Next, imagine us using it somewhere else in the program

```js
const add = (x,y) => {
  const sum = x + y
  console.log("debug sum", sum)
  return sum
}

const result = [1,2,3].reduce(add, 0)
// "debug sum 1"
// "debug sum 3"
// "debug sum 6"

console.log(result)
// 6
```

What a nightmare! I didn't want all of those `debug` outputs in my console. Why can't I just use the `add` function without the logging? – or in other words, the intended effect of `add` is to sum two numbers, but it has a **side effect** of also writing to the console. – `add` is an **impure** function because it has a side effect.

> Can we say in this case, that function `activateAnUser` is pure?

No. `activateAnUser` has a side effect of logging to the console. No amount of added arguments is going to save you from that.

---

**How you can fix it**

We will use a very basic implementation of the `IO` monad. `IO` can effectively tame offensive, impure code and allow us work with it in a pure fashion. It's a very simple monad, so just be patient while reading it and you should be able to make sense of it.

```js
// IO monad
const IO = f => ({
  unsafePerformIO: f,
  chain: g => g(f())
})

// IO-safe log utility
const log = x => IO($ => (console.log(x), x))

// remove the log call from your function; that is not its job
const activateAnUser = (user, log) => {
  // i used Object.assign here to keep this snippet runnable
  // you can use {...user, active: true} in your code
  return Object.assign({}, user, {active: true})
}

// your main program
// activate a user, then display it
const main = user =>
  IO($ => activateAnUser(user)).chain(log)

// sample data
const user = { name: "Sławomir" }

// PURE above this line
// IMPURE below this line; unsafePerformIO logs to the console
main(user).unsafePerformIO()
```

Learn more about the [`IO Monad`](https://github.com/MostlyAdequate/mostly-adequate-guide/blob/master/ch8.md#old-mcdonald-had-effects) as implemented in JavaScript by a professor genius.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `log` does anything, it's still not a pure function. Creating the log entry **is** a side effect of the function, though a desired one, so there **is** a difference between calling it once, caching and resusing the result, and calling it 100 times with identical arguments.

Comment: But what if we separate `activateAUser` to an other package? Isn't it still pure? Just because it assumes, that log has side effect?

Comment: In my understanding, a function that accepts an inpure function as argument and executes it, cannot be pure. A pure function causes no side effect for any possible argument.